# How to save data when fragment in BottomNavigationView is changed?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

In my app, I use `BottomNavigationView` and on each fragment I have some elements.
On changing fragments my data that download is lost.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()` like this:

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2); //2 is number of pages that you want keep in memory and don't load again on click at its item.
```